# F# unbox<int> returns obj

Tags: f#, fsi

Perhaps a silly question, but why does the return value from `unbox` appear (in my F# Interactive session) to be typed as `obj` instead of the concrete type `int`? As far as I can understand (trying to apply existing knowledge from C#) if it's typed as `obj` then it's still boxed. Example follows:

```
> (unbox<int> >> box<int>) 42;;
val it : obj = 42
> 42;;
val it : int = 42
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function composition `(f >> g) v` means `g (f (v))`, so you're actually calling `box<int>` at the end (and the call to `unbox<int>` is not necessary):

```
> box<int> (unbox<int> 42);;
val it : obj = 42

> box<int> 42;;
val it : obj = 42
```

The types are `box : 'T -> obj` and `unbox : obj -> 'T`, so the functions convert between boxed (objects) and value types (int). You can call `unbox<int> 42`, because F# automatically inserts conversion from `int` to `obj` when calling a function.

Comment: Jono - you might have noticed that the symbol is a bit similar to the pipeline symbol, so you can think of ``(f >> g) v`` as ``v |> f |> g`` and of ``(f << g) v`` as ``v |> g |> f``. See how the direction of the pipeline always matches the direction of the composition operator. Note: ``v |> g |> f`` is not equivalent to ``f <| g <| v``, because the latter is parsed as ``(f <| g) <| v``.

Comment: @Jono - I actually got pretty confused by your question for a moment :-).

Comment: @Tomas - LOL. You can just imagine how confusing the code looks to me as I learn F#. Without a solid grasp of all these funky operators, my code is best described as a dog's breakfast.

Answer (score 0):

On a related note: such a method is actually quite useful. I use it to deal with ["the type of an object expression is equal to the initial type"](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597446) behavior.

```
let coerce value = (box >> unbox) value

type A = interface end
type B = interface end

let x = 
  { new A
    interface B }

let test (b:B) = printf "%A" b

test x //doesn't compile: x is type A (but still knows how to relax)
test (coerce x) //works just fine
```